Fails to Initialize HTTP2 Server in Zephyr OS
I'm working on a Zephyr OS project and encountering an issue when trying to run the application in the QEMU emulator. The system boots up fine, but the HTTP2 server fails to initialize and keeps restarting. The error message indicates that the TLS communication is insecure due to the lack of an entropy device, and the HTTP2 server initialization fails repeatedly.
I dont have any real device.
# General config
CONFIG_MAIN_STACK_SIZE=3072
CONFIG_SYSTEM_WORKQUEUE_STACK_SIZE=2048
CONFIG_SHELL=y
CONFIG_LOG=y
CONFIG_ENTROPY_GENERATOR=y
CONFIG_TEST_RANDOM_GENERATOR=y
CONFIG_INIT_STACKS=y
CONFIG_ZVFS_OPEN_MAX=32
CONFIG_POSIX_API=y
CONFIG_FDTABLE=y
CONFIG_ZVFS_POLL_MAX=32

# Eventfd
CONFIG_EVENTFD=y

# Networking config
CONFIG_NETWORKING=y
CONFIG_NET_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NET_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NET_TCP=y
CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS=y
CONFIG_NET_CONNECTION_MANAGER=y
CONFIG_NET_SHELL=y
CONFIG_NET_STATISTICS=y
CONFIG_NET_STATISTICS_USER_API=y
CONFIG_NET_LOG=y

# JSON
CONFIG_JSON_LIBRARY=y

# HTTP parser
CONFIG_HTTP_PARSER_URL=y
CONFIG_HTTP_PARSER=y
CONFIG_HTTP_SERVER=y
CONFIG_HTTP_SERVER_WEBSOCKET=y

# Network buffers
CONFIG_NET_PKT_RX_COUNT=16
CONFIG_NET_PKT_TX_COUNT=16
CONFIG_NET_BUF_RX_COUNT=128
CONFIG_NET_BUF_TX_COUNT=128
CONFIG_NET_CONTEXT_NET_PKT_POOL=y

# IP address options
CONFIG_NET_IF_UNICAST_IPV6_ADDR_COUNT=3
CONFIG_NET_IF_MCAST_IPV6_ADDR_COUNT=4
CONFIG_NET_MAX_CONTEXTS=32
CONFIG_NET_MAX_CONN=32

# Network address config
CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_SETTINGS=y
CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_NEED_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_NEED_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_MY_IPV4_ADDR="192.0.2.1"
CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_PEER_IPV4_ADDR="192.0.2.2"
CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_MY_IPV4_GW="192.0.2.2"
CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_MY_IPV6_ADDR="2001:db8::1"
CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_PEER_IPV6_ADDR="2001:db8::2"

# TLS configuration
CONFIG_MBEDTLS=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_BUILTIN=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ENABLE_HEAP=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_HEAP_SIZE=60000
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_MAX_CONTENT_LEN=2048
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_USE_PSA_CRYPTO=n
CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_SOCKOPT_TLS=y
CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_TLS_MAX_CONTEXTS=6
CONFIG_TLS_CREDENTIALS=y
CONFIG_TLS_MAX_CREDENTIALS_NUMBER=5

# Networking tweaks
# Required to handle large number of consecutive connections,
# e.g. when testing with ApacheBench.
CONFIG_NET_TCP_TIME_WAIT_DELAY=0

# Device drivers
CONFIG_GPIO=y
CONFIG_LED=y

# Network debug config
CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_LOG_LEVEL_DBG=n
CONFIG_NET_HTTP_LOG_LEVEL_DBG=n
CONFIG_NET_IPV6_LOG_LEVEL_DBG=n
CONFIG_NET_IPV6_ND_LOG_LEVEL_DBG=n

error:
-- west build: running target run

[0/1] To exit from QEMU enter: 'CTRL+a, x'[QEMU] CPU: qemu32,+nx,+pae
SeaBIOS (version zephyr-v1.0.0-0-g31d4e0e-dirty-20200714_234759-fv-az50-zephyr)
Booting from ROM..
*** Booting Zephyr OS build v4.0.0-rc1-22-g14478cafa6a4 ***
[00:00:00.020,000] net_sock_tls: No entropy device on the system, TLS communication is insecure!
[00:00:00.020,000] net_config: Initializing network
[00:00:00.020,000] net_config: IPv4 address: 192.0.2.1
[00:00:00.120,000] net_config: IPv6 address: 2001:db8::1
[00:00:00.120,000] net_config: IPv6 address: 2001:db8::1
[00:00:00.120,000] smart_bulb_emulator: TLS setup completed
[00:00:00.120,000] net_http_server: All services failed (0)
[00:00:00.120,000] net_http_server: Failed to initialize HTTP2 server
[00:00:00.120,000] net_http_server: Re-starting server (-3)
[00:00:01.130,000] net_http_server: All services failed (0)
[00:00:01.130,000] net_http_server: Failed to initialize HTTP2 server
[00:00:01.130,000] net_http_server: Re-starting server (-3)
[00:00:02.140,000] net_http_server: All services failed (0)
[00:00:02.140,000] net_http_server: Failed to initialize HTTP2 server
[00:00:02.140,000] net_http_server: Re-starting server (-3)
uart:~$ qemu-system-i386: terminating on signal 2


Did you ask on the Zephyr mailing list? I'd never heard of Zephyr before, but was curious and looked into this a bit, and now I have a feeling the problem is the CONFIG_ENTROPY_GENERATOR=y line, since it seems like there are no real entropy drivers for when you're running in qemu instead of on bare metal on a supported SBC/embedded platform. The lack of a good entropy source appears to be the reason that  CONFIG_TEST_RANDOM_GENERATOR=y exists; to let you get away with insufficient entropy during development. Be sure to fix it before production deployment.
